# How to make a "perfect" 2 grid layout using RecyclerView and a single ImageView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a 2-grid layout using a `RecyclerView` with `GridView` as the layout manager. So far I have a single image view under a relative layout in the `xml` file, but it's never "perfectly" aligned to the center. Also, when trying to drag the single image view in the `xml` file Design tab, the image "jumps" when I try to make it more "centerish" (Won't let me drag the image to the correct position).

What do I need to change, in order to make the 2-grid with a single image view be centered?

This is the xml code for the single item:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView               
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the RecyclerView xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.166"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: hai issue fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of giving width to `ImageView`, try making it `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView               
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try this whether it will helps you or not.

Comment: what should be instead of `frame2` in my code? because for me it's not defined